# How to get all transitions for specified workflow

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I'm writing Jira plugin and I need to get `all transitions` available `in specified workflow`. It would be good to get those transitions by workflow name. I can't find any class that can list it. Is it possible to get it without using rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from the API documents, the [`WorkflowManager`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/WorkflowManager.html) can be used to call [`getWorkflow(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/WorkflowManager.html#getWorkflow(java.lang.String)) which returns a [`JiraWorkflow`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/JiraWorkflow.html) based off the provided workflow name string.

Then from that you should be able to get all the transitions in the workflow, I am just not sure what exactly you would need to call within the [`JiraWorkflow`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/JiraWorkflow.html).

I imagine possibly [`getAllActions()`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/JiraWorkflow.html#getAllActions()).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to get available workflow transitions on current state then you can try with following code

```
IssueWorkflowManager issueWflwMan = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueWorkflowManager.class);
        Collection<ActionDescriptor> coll = issueWflwMan.getAvailableActions(issue,authenticationContext.getUser());
for (ActionDescriptor res : coll) {
     s.o.p(res.getName());
}
```

Comment: I need to get all transitions in specified workflow. For exaple i have workflow with name "ABC" and it has 10 transitions between states (Open->Close, Close->Reopen... etc.), I need to get all of them (name and ID)

Comment: As @Welsh said, use have to try with methods in  Jiraworkflow  interface